Validate jwt for human user or another application
I have jwt auth in my application, the auth happens like this : parse token, validate expiration, check if user(username is taken from the subject) exists in the db. Now i have aws lambda that needs to access certain endpoints in the app, so it needs jwt token. The flow for lambda: lambda gets client id and client secret from the aws secrets, logins with them with the accessible endpoint and uses the jwt that was returned by the endpoint. But the thing is that for this flow i probably need 2 db's now for regular user (with username) and for the apps (with client id and client secret) and for the jwt token validation i will probably need to check 2 db's too to verify that token is valid. What is the best way i can implement smth like this (or maybe there is a better approach)? (my app uses java spring)
